# Change data source of tableView after selected row

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have table view with rows...after I selecting one item I want to show tableView with a new data source.

I tried to implement:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
    Game *game = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //name your class names with capitals
    NSMutableArray *arrayToBeAdded= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:newgamearray];
    [ListContent removeAllObjects];
    [ListContent addObject:arrayToBeAdded];
```

but I getting exeption in the

```
[ListContent removeAllObjects];
```

Implementation of the init:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellID = @"cellSgames";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellID] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    Gmage *game = [self.ListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In the .h file i declare:

```
NSArray AllList;
NSMutableArray ListContent;
```

any ideas?

Comment: why you want to show tableView with a new data source?

Comment: after selecting an item i want to show his child Items

Comment: @vadim which exception are you getting? Where is ListContent declared? What is it?

Comment: @vadim you didn't post the init but cellForRowAtIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the current list, create new UITableViewController with your desired data source. If you are using the UINavigationController it will create a better user experience and you will avoid your current problem.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    InnerTableViewController *innerTVC = [[InnerTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InnerTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:innerTVC animated:YES];
    [innerTVC release];
}
```

Comment: I want it to change on the same table/view without changing views...i want it to work quickly.

Comment: I personaly think you will not get much faster result by manipulating the dataSource as you still need to remove, and update the list and keep track of everything in one big controller class. But if that is your choice let me know what is ListContent and show your code where you initialize it.

Comment: @vadim you won't get it quickly the way you are trying to do it. Push to a new tableviewcontroller instance is the way to go.

Comment: i try the tableviewcontroller ... maybe you have some examples?

Comment: @Cyprian thanks for the example. So basically what I need to do is to create another interfase (UIViewControlerer) with same design xib file as showen and when clicking on the first tableView I should open the second tableView, so probobly when i do back i will be transferd to the first tableView with the selected value right?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you are resetting the array in didselect method and reloading your table view with new content it should work.

In your case i think at line:
[ListContent removeAllObjects];

ListContent is not a valid pointer. I don't see a reason to crash it here.

Comment: 1 more thing instead of: [ListContent addObject:arrayToBeAdded]; you should do like:   [ListContent addObjectsFromArray:arrayToBeAdded];

Comment: when its comes to those line its then stops on the main before the int retVal = UIapplicationMain...

Comment: the code shared is not enough to tell what exactly is the problem but you can try implementing similar way in a simple application and can figure out the problem. I have tried like this it's working for me.